# Openvidu subscriber volume on android

Tags: android, openvidu

So using openvidu to setup two way calling but I noticed an issue when it’s being used on an android device.

The android phone has multiple volume controls, one of them is the media volume, so if the user watching as a subscriber has their media volume low they can’t hear the publisher speaking until they turn it up, and a few people don’t even know this exists.

By default the volume up hardware button seems to control the phone volume, or rather it seems to control the last one that was used.

It’s a little concerning that many people won’t know about this and will complain they can’t hear anything, unlike on the iPhone where the one button controls the overall volume.

I doubt this is possible but are we able to increase the android media volume
With JavaScript somehow? I very much doubt it but I’m not sure how to solve this problem if we can’t. I know we can control the video element volume itself but that seems to have no impact on the phone volume itself. As in I can turn the phone media volume all the way up but control the video element separate instead of them working together.